# Filtering javascript from site content PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, keyword

So I'm making a script to check the keyword density of a page based off the URL the user submits and I have been using strip_tags but it doesn't seem to be completely filtering the javascript and other code from the actual word content on the site. Is there a better way to filter between the code content on a page and the actual word content?

```
if(isset($_POST['url'])){
$url = $_POST['url'];
$str = strip_tags(file_get_contents($url));
$words      = str_word_count(strtolower($str),1);
$word_count = array_count_values($words);

foreach ($word_count as $key=>$val) {
    $density = ($val/count($words))*100;
        echo "$key - COUNT: $val, DENSITY: ".number_format($density,2)."%<br/>\n";
}
}
```

Comment: What isn't it stripping?

Comment: gettime - COUNT: 1, DENSITY: 0.06%
event - COUNT: 1, DENSITY: 0.06%
js' - COUNT: 1, DENSITY: 0.06%
var - COUNT: 2, DENSITY: 0.12%
f - COUNT: 3, DENSITY: 0.18%
getelementsbytagname - COUNT: 1, DENSITY: 0.06%

Comment: ^some examples of things that shouldn't be in there

Comment: Those aren't tags, those are part of Javascript that's between tags.

Comment: How can I strip the javascript from my string then?

Comment: Use an HTML DOM parser, find all the `<script>` elements, and remove them. You should probably also do the same thing with `<style>`.

Comment: Did you ask and then delete an earlier question where I made the same suggestion about using a DOM parser?

Comment: No, I was having issues with some other php code using $_GET that I figured out and deleted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have written 2 functions for this:

```
/**
 * Removes all Tags provided from an Html string
 *
 * @param string   $str    The Html String
 * @param string[] $tagArr An Array with all Tag Names to be removed
 *
 * @return string The Html String without the tags
 */
function removeTags($str, $tagArr)
{
    foreach ($tagArr as $tag) {
        $str = preg_replace('#<' . $tag . '(.*?)>(.*?)</' . $tag . '>#is', '', $str);
    }
    return $str;
}

/**
 * cleans some html string
 *
 * @param string $str some html string
 *
 * @return string the cleaned string
 */
function filterHtml($str)
{
    //Remove Tags
    $str = removeTags($str, ['script', 'style']);

    //Remove all Tags, but not the Content
    $str = preg_replace('/<[^>]*>/', ' ', $str);

    //Remove Linebreaks and Tabs
    $str = str_replace(["\n", "\t", "\r"], ' ', $str);

    //Remove Double Whitespace
    while (strpos($str, '  ') !== false) {
        $str = str_replace('  ', ' ', $str);
    }

    //Return trimmed
    return trim($str);
}
```

Working Example

```
$fileContent     = file_get_contents('http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25537377/filtering-html-from-site-content-php');
$filteredContent = filterHtml($fileContent);
var_dump($filteredContent);
```

Comment: Still getting blank white screen, not sure what the issue is

Comment: @mako i have improved the method to not show script tags and not needed whitespaces. I Also have added a working example. Please verify, that your code is realy called, if you use it.

Comment: Seems to strip most of the javascript out that I was seeing

Comment: @mako, since you updated question, i have provided a second function, which can remove every wanted tag with content, via blacklist.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is to parse the HTML so you have a DOM like structure you can iterate over and access the content of the different nodes.

You can use [PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/)