# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' php

Tags: php, arrays, php-parse-error

I have the following line of code which has been giving me this error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' php
```

For this line:

```
$str = removeTags($str, ['script', 'style']);
```

Why am I getting that error? I read online that maybe it is because I don't have the latest php version? Site is running in wordpress.

Comment: What php version do you have installed?

Comment: you most likely read correctly. what version of php are you running?

Comment: It's your PHP version. Use `()`

Comment: 5.2.4 on the wordpress site

Comment: Seems like that line comes from the answer given http://stackoverflow.com/a/25537416/ in your other question.

Comment: Yeah I tested that code on a different site with a diff php vers.

Answer (score 4):

You need PHP >= 5.4.0 for the `[]` syntax.  Use:

```
$str = removeTags($str, array('script', 'style'));
```